# HippoCMS Restcall content relative link issue

Tags: hippocms

I have already add the rest support (link)of my website.  the CMS and my website are under different domain. when I used restcall to pull the contents like html code "  the contents will automatically convert to      site is for hippo site and rest is for rest call mount point.
so  obvious the relative path does not support if we use rest call to pull contents from cms to other websites.
I am just wondering that is there anyway to keep same relative url after rest call and instead using absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the long thread posted here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/hippo-community/L417REGg2pY/YPtawvh0M8IJ